# Not possible to move/rename weblinks?

Tags: box-api

I don't see any way to move or rename weblinks in the box-ios-sdk-v2 or web APIs. It this just not possible or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible right now.  What are you using weblinks for BTW?

Comment: I was going to represent them as .webloc files in a OS X file system. I wanted to let the user rename/move them just like other files/folders. Looks like I'll just have to either not display them at all, or forbid making any changes to them.